# RPN calculator in C

Tags: c, homework, math-expression-eval, calculator

I had to write a RPN calculator in C as one of my homework problems, but if someone could critique my code and suggest any improvements, that would be fantastic! I haven't added any overflow errors or input errors, but I will add that eventually.

My code takes operands and operators from the command line (e.g., 3 4 - would return -1), and sends it to the decode function which uses the pop and push functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void push(float stack[], float value, int *currStack)
{
    int i = *currStack;

    while (i != 0)
    {
        stack[i] = stack[i-1];
        i--;
    }

    stack[0] = value;
    *currStack += 1;
}

void pop(float stack[], char operation, int *currStack)
{
    int i;

    switch (operation)
    {
        case '+':
            stack[0] = stack[1] + stack[0];
            break;
        case '-':
            stack[0] = stack[1] - stack[0];
            break;
        case '*':
            stack[0] = stack[1] * stack[0];
            break;
        case '/':
            stack[0] = stack[1] / stack[0];
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid character.");
            break;
    }

    for (i=1;i<*currStack;i++)
    {
        float temp = stack[i];
        stack[i] = stack[i+1];
        stack[i+1] = temp;
    }

    *currStack -= 1;
}

int decode(char **instring, float *outval, int size)
{
    int i=0, currStack=0;
    float stack[size/2];

    for (i=1;i<size;i++)
    {           
        if (atof(instring[i]))
            push(stack, atof(instring[i]), &currStack);
        else
            pop(stack, *instring[i], &currStack);

        *outval = stack[0];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float result;
    decode(argv, &result, argc);

    printf("The answer is: %.3f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this code seems to be missing any grouping operators like '(' and ')'

Comment: @user3629249  RPN calculators don't have grouping operators.  Each operator takes effect immediately.  If you want to say 2*(3+1), you'd write it 2 3 1 + *

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> for (i=1;i<*currStack;i++)
> {
>     float temp = stack[i];
>     stack[i] = stack[i+1];
>     stack[i+1] = temp;
> }
> ```

This is more complicated than it needs to be.

```
float temp = stack[1];
for ( i = 1; i < *currStack; i++ )
{
    stack[i] = stack[i+1];
}
stack[*currStack] = temp;
```

This version has the exact same effect but does `*currStack + 1` assignments where your original does `*currStack * 3 - 3` assignments (although that may drop to `*currStack * 2 - 2` assignments with good register management by the compiler).

We can do even better since we don't care about the value that is at `stack[1]` before we start.

```
for ( i = 1; i < *currStack; i++ )
{
    stack[i] = stack[i+1];
}
```

The `for` loop is sufficient.  We don't need to muck around with `temp` at all.  It's just junk data at this point.

Note:  I'm not disputing [vnp's point that the copy is unnecessary](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/79740/53820).  I'm just saying that if you do do the copy, you don't actually have to copy the `stack[1]` value.  And you certainly don't have to copy `stack[1]` once per element in the stack.

> ```
>     default:
>         printf("Invalid character.");
>         break;
> }
> ```

You don't actually need the `break;` there.  It's all right to let it fall out of the `default` case on its own.  It won't hurt anything, but I think it's more readable to set off `default` slightly by having it not `break`.

> ```
> int decode(char **instring, float *outval, int size)
> ```

You say that `decode` is supposed to `return` an `int` but you never return anything.  You could declare this of type `void`.

```
void decode(char **instring, float *outval, int size)
```

Then no one would expect it to return anything.

> ```
> float stack[size/2];
>
> for (i=1;i<size;i++)
> ```

You should probably comment why this works.  Note that it's only because `argc` is one greater than the number of arguments that it does.  This shows up implicitly in the way that you start with `i=1` but could be clearer.  As a general rule, any time you do something clever, you should comment to explain it.  Otherwise, you have to be clever again to read the code.

> ```
> for (i=1;i<size;i++)
> {           
>     if (atof(instring[i]))
>         push(stack, atof(instring[i]), &currStack);
>     else
>         pop(stack, *instring[i], &currStack);
>
>     *outval = stack[0];
> }
> ```

You assign a value to `*outval` on every iteration of the loop but only use it once.  You could do this outside the loop with the same ultimate effect.

```
for ( i = 1; i < size; ++i ) {
    double temp;
    if ( temp = atof(instring[i]) ) {
        push(stack, temp, &currStack);
    } else {
        pop(stack, *instring[i], &currStack);
    }
}

*outval = stack[0];
```

You also don't need to calculate `atof(instring[i])` twice.  Save it the first time.

I added curly braces around the statements in the `if`/`else`.  The single statement version is susceptible to a class of typo bugs that is rather hard to diagnose.

There is an argument that `++i` is faster than `i++`.  It's not a big difference and a good compiler should be able to optimize this out, but it doesn't hurt anything to use the prefix notation.

Your code doesn't allow for values of `0.0` and will display "Invalid character" in that case.  Yet that's a valid value.  Another possibility would be

```
    if ( temp = atof(instring[i]) || ! strcmp(instring[i], "0.0") ) {
```

which would allow for `0.0`, although it only supports one format.  An alternative would be an `is_zero` function which could do a more exhaustive check.

The string manipulation to check for a number is more expensive (in terms of time) than checking for an operator.  Checking for an operator only requires checking two characters to establish that it is an operator.

```
if ( ! instring[i][1] && is_operator(in_string[i][0] ) {
    pop(stack, *instring[i], &currStack);
} else if ( temp = atof(instring[i]) || ! strcmp(instring[i], "0.0") ) {
    push(stack, temp, &currStack);
} else {
    printf("Invalid argument:  [%s].", in_string[i]);
}
```

Then you just need an `is_operator` function:

```
int is_operator(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

The `atof` statement returns a `double`, but you are only using `float` variables.  It would be better to make `stack`, `outval`, etc. hold `double` values rather than just `float` values.  That would save the implicit conversions as well.  Note that [`%lf` in `printf` expects a `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368369/2625983) as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely be taking all your suggestions in account to revise my code. I'll make this my accepted answer :)

Answer (score 5):

First, you have a top of stack at 0. This is very unconventional, and results in a lot of unnecessary data moves. Having a top of stack at `currStack` would make code much simpler. For example, `push` becomes just

```
*currStack++ = value;
```

and `pop`

```
case '+':
    currStack[-2] += currStack[-1];
    --currStack;
    break;
```

etc.

Second, `pop` means just that, pop a value from the stack. Your function performs an arithmetic operation and should be renamed accordingly, `apply_operation` perhaps.

Finally, I recommend to change a `decode` signature to `float decode(char **, int)`.  Returning results via size effect makes the code harder to reason about, and there must be a serious reason for such decision. As much as possible try to utilize return values.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! That certainly makes a lot of sense, and I'm not sure why I didn't do it that way.

Also, I had the size integer as an argument of the decode function because my problem set stated that I had to take an undetermined amount of strings, so I figured I would just do that by dividing the number of command line arguments by 2 to get the stack size.

Answer (score 4):

### Use of `float`

You should nearly almost use `double` instead of `float`.  That advice applies here too.  For example, the C library math functions all work with `double`s; that includes `atof()`, which returns a `double` that you degraded into a `float`.

### Compiler warning

These kinds of warnings almost always indicate a logic bug.  Indeed, `decode()` never returns anything, even though it was supposed to return an `int`.

> ```
> $ clang -Wall -o rpn rpn.c
> rpn.c:65:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
> }
> ^
> 1 warning generated.
> ```

### Bug

You fail to handle `0` operands:

> ```
> $ ./rpn 1 3 0 '*' +
> Invalid character.The answer is: 0.000
> ```

The expected answer is 1.000.  I got it to print 0.000, but the output is actually arbitrary, since this triggers a stack underflow.

### Implementation

Your function signatures are weird.  For example, in

> ```
> void push(float stack[], float value, int *currStack)
> ```

… I would have expected `stack` and `currStack` to be placed together, since the two parameters together conceptually constitute a stack.  Better yet, you should just structure them together to form a simple data structure:

```
typedef struct {
    double *data;
    size_t size;
} stack;

void push(stack *s, double datum);
```

As has been mentioned, your stack is laid out backwards in memory, and you are manipulating the wrong end of the array.

`pop()`, as you have written it, isn't the stack operation it should be.  Rather, it performs an arithmetic operation (pop → pop → push), making it misnamed, and leaving you without a proper stack-popping function.

`decode()` would be better named `rpn_calc()`.  Again, `instring` and `size` should be adjacent to each other.  (In fact, this is a pretty strong convention in C: pass a pointer, followed by its associated array size).

The core of the calculator should look more like this:

```
void rpn_calc(stack *s, char *tokens[], size_t n_tokens) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n_tokens; i++) {
        const char *token = tokens[i];
        if (0 == strcmp(token, "+")) {
            push(s, pop(s) + pop(s));
        } else if (0 == strcmp(token, "-")) {
            double x = pop(s);
            push(s, pop(s) - x);
        } else if (0 == strcmp(token, "*")) {
            push(s, pop(s) * pop(s));
        } else if (0 == strcmp(token, "/")) {
            double x = pop(s);
            push(s, pop(s) / x);
        } else {
            push(s, atof(token));
        }
    }
}
```

To get the result, `main()` just needs to peek at the top of the stack afterwards.

Comment: You should explain why you wrote `pop(s) + pop(s)` but used a temporary variable instead of `pop(s) - pop(s)`, since this is something that might surprise many C programmers.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if I run your program like this?

```
rpn 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

I guess it crashes, or it might do anything else, since it invokes *undefined behavior*.

This is why you should not use tricks like the `size/2` array size and check each array access whether the index is valid, i.e. `0 <= index <= arraylength`. Since a C program cannot ask for the length of an arbitrary array, you have to pass the array as a tuple `(start, size)` or something equivalent.